# Return all records and display message if record is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with content from our distributor, and their database files are not the best in the world. So, I am doing the best I can do, with what I have.

I have two tables, `HLItems` and `HLImages`.

I need to return ALL products from `HLItems`. And for the rows that do not exist, I need to display a message.

- If exist = 'Front Cover'
- If not exist = 'No Cover'

This is what I have tried, but it is not working. It returns all the records even the NULL rows, are getting 'Front Cover' displayed.

Front Cover is what is displayed in the record if the record exists. Else, nothing.

With RIGHT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT    
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 HLImages.Caption 
                     FROM HLImages  
                     RIGHT OUTER JOIN HLItems ON HLImages.ItemNo = HLItems.ItemNo) 
           THEN 'Front Cover'
           ELSE 'No Cover' 
     END) AS thumbnail, 
    Title, ItemNo, InternetCategoryID
FROM  
    HLItems
WHERE 
    (InternetCategoryID = 11)
```

Selecting just the column

```
SELECT  
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Caption
                     FROM HLImages
                     WHERE Caption = 'Front Cover') 
           THEN 'Front Cover'
           ELSE 'No Cover' 
     END) AS thumbnail, 
    Title, ItemNo, InternetCategoryID
FROM
    HLItems
WHERE (InternetCategoryID = 11)
```

Something like this, is what is expected. (ItemNo, and Caption.. shown below for simplicity)

> 297110 - Front Cover
>   297110 - NULL
>   49043128 - Front Cover
>   49014741 - NULL
>   50563362 - Front Cover
>   50301310 - NULL

Comment: can you please show data and desired result. just want to get the correct translation of the problem

Comment: maSTAShuFu, updated information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` in

```
SELECT TOP 1 HLImages.Caption 
FROM HLImages  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN HLItems ON HLImages.ItemNo = HLItems.ItemNo
```

has the effect, that all rows from `HLItems` (the right table) are included in the result regardless if a matching row from `HLImages` exists. That means, that this query in an `EXISTS` is always true. That is why you always got `'Front Cover'`from that `CASE`.

(The `EXISTS` can only be false if there were no rows in `HLItems`. But if there weren't, the outer query wouldn't have a non empty result, so you wouldn't see `'No Cover'` too in that case.)

And that

```
SELECT TOP 1 Caption
FROM HLImages
WHERE Caption = 'Front Cover'
```

will always result in a non empty set if there is any image with the caption `'Front Cover'`, regardless of the product it belongs to. I assume there are such images, so the same as above applies.

Try a simple correlated subquery using a `WHERE`.

```
SELECT    
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM HLImages  
                     WHERE HLImages.ItemNo = HLItems.ItemNo
                           AND HLImages.Caption = 'Front Cover')
           THEN 'Front Cover'
           ELSE 'No Cover' 
     END) AS thumbnail, 
    Title, ItemNo, InternetCategoryID
FROM  
    HLItems
WHERE 
    (InternetCategoryID = 11)
```

You can remove the `AND HLImages.Caption = 'Front Cover'` if you only want to see if any image for the product exists, regardless of the caption.

Comment: I have to leave the AND HLImages.Caption = 'Front Cover'.... in, as if not, then it will return more records, that the intended results.

Comment: @CodingEE: I just wasn't sure if I got you right regarding that point. That's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the expected result a humble (maybe imperfect) solution would be to use outer apply

```
SELECT   
case when image.Caption is not null then 'Front Cover'
    else 'No Cover'
end
as thumbnail, 
Title, 
ItemNo, 
InternetCategoryID
FROM  HLItems item
outer apply(
    SELECT   top 1 HLImages.Caption AS Caption
    FROM  HLImages 
    where HLImages.ItemNo = item.ItemNo
) image
WHERE (item.InternetCategoryID = 11)
```

Comment: Hello, Levi. Please look at the example, in my main post. Also, Your code has several errors in it as well. Was unable to run it.